# What is the benefit of max_digits10 being 0 on references to floating point types?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, precision, numeric-limits

In C++11, what is the advantage of `std::numeric_limits<Type>::max_digits10` returning 0 for a `Type` that is a reference to floating point number?

For example:

```
constexpr int precisionPositive(const float &floatVal)
{
  using numericType    = std::remove_reference<decltype(floatVal)>::type;
  constexpr int digits = std::numeric_limits<numericType>::max_digits10;

  return digits;
}

constexpr int precisionZero(const float &floatVal)
{
  using numericType    = decltype(floatVal);
  constexpr int digits = std::numeric_limits<numericType>::max_digits10;

  return digits;
}
```

The `precisionPositive` returns 9 and `precisionZero` returns 0.

Under what circumstances would the zero value helpful, as opposed to giving a compile time error?

Comment: I _assume_ the intent is to flag `std::numeric_limits<SomeRandomBigInt>::max_digits10` as `0`, and `float&` also got hit as an unintended side effect, but that's purely guessing.

Answer (score 2):

As per the C++ standard (n4659), in the `numeric_limits` class template the default value for `max_digits10` is `0`.

> **21.3.4 Class template numeric_limits [numeric.limits]**
>
> ```
> namespace std {
> template<class T> class numeric_limits {
> public:
> ...  
> static constexpr int max_digits10 = 0;
> ```

And it is only when the template is specialized for `float`, `double` etc, `max_digits10` is given a particular value.

Consider the specialization for **`float`**.

> **21.3.4.2 numeric_limits specializations [numeric.special]**
>
> ```
> namespace std {
> template<> class numeric_limits<float> {
> public:
> ...
> static constexpr int max_digits10 = 9;
> ```

The implementations also follow this. See GCC's Standard C++ Library header [limits](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/limits.html) for example.

So, except for specializations where `max_digits10` is given a particular value, the default value is `0` and **therefore the value of `max_digits10` for references to floating point types is also `0`.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proper answer for the question "why". Buy I might use this code:

C++11:

```
template<typename T>
    using bare_value_t=typename
        std::decay<T>::type;
```

C++14:

```
template<typename T>
    using bare_value_t=
        std::decay_t<T>;
```

C++20:

```
template<typename T>
    using bare_value_t=
        std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
```

And:

```
template<typename T>
    using limits=
        std::numeric_limits<bare_value_t<T> >;

cout<<limits<float&>::max_digits10;
```